# What is the best way to implement user Live status management on web?

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, web

I have a scenarion.

1. My users logged in my project and current status = available
2. If users getting task , your status = on working
3. My task dispatcher sends jobs to whoever is "available" in the system at that moment.
4. I keep users status in mysql
5. But sometimes 2 tasks are assigned to the user at the same time.
6. Because when the second task starts to be assigned before the status is updated in mysql, that user sees it as "available".

For example;

1. task 2021-08-25 is dispatching at 10:00:01.
2. task 2021-08-25 is dispatching at 10:00:02.

But same user

How can I handle this situation ? Waiting for your suggestions

Backend : PHP Laravel
Database : Mysql

Comment: So the first task sees that Bob is available and then the second task sees that Bob is available and then the first task gets assigned to Bob and then the second task gets assigned to Bob? Use transactions

Comment: hi @user253751 could you please explain more ?
Also these can run at different times. So parallel process.

Comment: Why does the second task not see that Bob already has a task?

Comment: @user253751 because I requested status update for mysql but it has not been updated yet.
I mean, when I send an update request to a table, mysql sees that user available when another task arrives. Because its status has not been updated yet. So this is a one-second event.